# resize imageView on UIButton while moving

Tags: iphone, uiview, frame, touchesmoved

In my application I have an overview of objects. Each object is a UIButton, which has its own UIImage (button.imageView). The user can drag objects around. Thereby, objects in the upper part of the display are considered to be 'in the back' while objects in the lower part are 'in the front'. Objects in the back are displayed smaller than objects in the front. I want the objects to dynamically resize while moving from 'front' to 'back' and vice-versa.

For this purpose, I use the following code (in a subclass of UIButton):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGFloat h = newHeight;
    CGFloat w = newWidth;

    CGRect target;
    target.size.height = h;
    target.size.width = w;
    self.frame = target;
}
```

This was working very nice up until iOS 4.2. Now we see very strange behaviour: while the resizing works when moving objects from 'front' to 'back' (i.e., from large to small), it DOES NOT work when moving object from 'back' to 'front' (i.e., from small to large).

Any idea what could cause this problem? How would you implement the 'resize while moving'?

Comment: add `[self setNeedsDisplay]`? to the end there?  No idea, sorry.

Comment: Have you explicitly `setClipsToBounds = NO`